# R assigning colors manually in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am assigning colors manually like below. But ggplot only assigns colors to A and B and not other values. Also I want NA in the data to be colored black.
I am manually defining color for each value and then passing it to scale_fill_manual to reflect on the plot
Here is my data

```
test1<- structure(list(rn = c("SB38331511", "SB4441518", 
    "IA/421851526", "SB51141624", "SB54978171", 
    "SB54978171", "SB6447173", 
    "SB6447173", "SB66854171825", 
    "SB6685412825", "SB1231825", "SB7439971922", 
    "SB74399181922", "SB85323113", 
    "SB853218113", "SB38331511", "SB4441518", 
    "SB421851526", "SB51141624", "SB54978171", 
    "SB54978171", "SB6447173", 
    "SB6447173", "SB66854171825", 
    "SB6685412825", "SB1231825", "SB7439971922", 
    "SB74399181922", "SB85323113", 
    "SB853218113", "SB38331511", "SB4441518", 
    "SB421851526", "SB51141624", "SB54978171", 
    "SB54978171", "SB6447173", 
    "SB6447173", "SB66854171825", 
    "SB6685412825", "SB1231825", "SB7439971922", 
    "SB74399181922", "SB85323113", 
    "SB853218113", "SB38331511", "SB4441518", 
    "SB421851526", "SB51141624", "SB54978171", 
    "SB54978171", "SB6447173", 
    "SB6447173", "SB66854171825", 
    "SB6685412825", "SB1231825", "SB7439971922", 
    "SB74399181922", "SB85323113", 
    "SB853218113", "SB38331511", "SB4441518", 
    "SB421851526", "SB51141624", "SB54978171", 
    "SB54978171", "SB6447173", 
    "SB6447173", "SB66854171825", 
    "SB6685412825", "SB1231825", "SB7439971922", 
    "SB74399181922", "SB85323113", 
    "SB853218113", "SB38331511", "SB4441518", 
    "SB421851526", "SB51141624", "SB54978171", 
    "SB54978171", "SB6447173", 
    "SB6447173", "SB66854171825", 
    "SB6685412825", "SB1231825", "SB7439971922", 
    "SB74399181922", "SB85323113", 
    "SB853218113", "SB38331511", "SB4441518", 
    "SB421851526", "SB51141624", "SB54978171", 
    "SB54978171", "SB6447173", 
    "SB6447173", "SB66854171825", 
    "SB6685412825", "SB1231825", "SB7439971922", 
    "SB74399181922", "SB85323113", 
    "SB853218113", "SB38331511", "SB4441518", 
    "SB421851526", "SB51141624", "SB54978171", 
    "SB54978171", "SB6447173", 
    "SB6447173", "SB66854171825", 
    "SB6685412825", "SB1231825", "SB7439971922", 
    "SB74399181922", "SB85323113", 
    "SB853218113"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
    13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), .Label = c("z2", 
    "z1", "A", "BD", "RB", "BDS", "G1", "G3", "BD1", "BD2", "Dates", 
    "GA", "BDA."), class = "factor"), value = c("A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A/B", 
    "A", "A", "A/B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
    "A", "A", "55.1", "A-2", "A-2", "A-2", "A-2", "A-2", "A-2", 
    "A-2", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "4444"", "5555", "5555", 
    "5555", "5555", "5555", "4444/1998", "5555", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "B")), row.names = c(NA, -120L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000002641ef0>, class = c("data.table", 
    "data.frame"))
```

Then I assign color like below

```
color = rep(NA, length=length(test1$value))
color[which(test1$value=="A")] = "red"
color[which(test1$value=="B")] = "blue"
color[which(test1$value=="A/B")] = "yellow"
color[which(test1$value=="4444")] = "orange"
color[which(test1$value=="5555")] = "pink"
color[which(test1$value=="55.1")] = "magenta"
color[which(test1$value=="4444/5555")] = "brown"
color[which(test1$value=="A-2")] = "gold"
color[which(test1$value=="NA")] = "black"
#Then make a plot to reflect the colors
ggplot(test1, aes(y = rn, x = variable, fill = value)) + geom_tile() + theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text.x = element_blank(), text = element_text(size=35)) + geom_text(aes(label=value), size=18) + labs(x="Seg", y= "Id ", fill = "Div", Title= "Myplot")+ scale_fill_manual(values=color)
```

Comment: Please make your problem reproducible so others can help. See more here [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a named vector to `scale_fill_manual` :

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(test1, aes(y = rn, x = variable, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() + 
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(), 
        strip.text.x = element_blank(), 
        text = element_text(size=3)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=value), size=3) + 
  labs(x="Seg", y= "Id ", fill = "Div", 
       title= "Myplot")+ 
  scale_fill_manual(values=setNames(color, test1$value))
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak! Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

```
    cols <- c( "#F00E0E", "#000BFF")
plot(fs1, col = cols[1], lwd.obs = 2, xlab = "Time", ylab = "name2", 
ylim=c(.95,1),ci=FALSE)
lines(fs2, col = cols[2], lty =2 ,ci=FALSE)
legend ("topright", col = c("black", cols[1], cols[2]),


    lty = c(1, 1, 2), bty = "n", lwd = rep(2, 3), c("x",
                                                    "y", "z"))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65627207/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.